# Unable to use USB dongle based on USB-serial converter chip

Tags: linux, usb

I have a USB Zigbee dongle, but I'm unable to connect to it. It briefly shows up in `/dev/ttyUSB0`, but then quickly disappears. I see the following output in the console:

```
$ dmesg --follow
...
[  738.365561] usb 1-10: new full-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[  738.607730] usb 1-10: New USB device found, idVendor=1a86, idProduct=7523, bcdDevice= 2.64
[  738.607737] usb 1-10: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  738.607739] usb 1-10: Product: USB Serial
[  738.619446] ch341 1-10:1.0: ch341-uart converter detected
[  738.633501] usb 1-10: ch341-uart converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[  738.732348] audit: type=1130 audit(1632606446.974:2212): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=brltty-device@sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:01.3-0000:03:00.0-usb1-1\x2d10 comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
[  738.768081] audit: type=1130 audit(1632606447.007:2213): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=brltty@-sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:01.3-0000:03:00.0-usb1-1\x2d10 comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
[  738.776433] usb 1-10: usbfs: interface 0 claimed by ch341 while 'brltty' sets config #1
[  738.783508] ch341-uart ttyUSB0: ch341-uart converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[  738.783521] ch341 1-10:1.0: device disconnected
[  739.955783] input: BRLTTY 6.4 Linux Screen Driver Keyboard as /devices/virtual/input/input35
...
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The problem here is BRLTTY, a program that "provides access to the Linux/Unix console (when in text mode) for a blind person using a refreshable braille display".

If you are not blind, you can disable BRLTTY in two different ways:

### Remove udev rules

BRLTTY uses udev rules to get permissions to mess with the TTYs without being root. You can disable these rules by overriding the rules shipped by your distro with `/dev/null`:

```bsh
for f in /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/*brltty*.rules; do
    sudo ln -s /dev/null "/etc/udev/rules.d/$(basename "$f")"
done
sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
```

### Disable service

The BRLTTY service is launched by the `brltty.path` service. This service can be completely prevented from ever starting by running by doing the following:

```
$ sudo systemctl mask brltty.path
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/brltty.path → /dev/null.
```

Comment: You can also just uninstall the whole thing. If you want to use any USB-serial device, another thing that you may want to purge is `modemmanager` (which is spamming any serial like with "commands" able to confuse or even *brick* any device which is not a kind of AT-modem).

Comment: Unfortunately, on Arch Linux, I can't :(. QEMU depends on brltty. But that is a good solution for folks on other systems!

Comment: On my Manjaro I disabled all brltty* services (listed by autocompletion) to get it to work, disabling only brltty.path didn't help.

Comment: @EvgEnZh thanks for sharing, and that comment sounds like an answer to me! Feel free to post it as one, I'm sure other folks would appreciate it too!

Comment: QEMU's dependency on `brltty` has semi-recently been made optional so you can now remove it with QEMU installed

Comment: @IsaacWoods Sounds like a great answer!

Comment: On Arch, I can't remove modemmanager because it's needed by modemmanager-qt, which is needed for plasma-nm, which is needed for KDE network management.

Comment: Disabling the service or doing method 1 did not work for me.

It works when i remove btltty program. If i`am right, this program is only needed for blind persons.

https://linux-packages.com/ubuntu-jammy-jellyfish/package/brltty

Comment: It helps me on Ubuntu 22.

Answer (score 22):

Shooting down a bit too much there. A [much less invasive solution](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=2002314#p2002314) was contributed by user *Blackisle* to [this post (*"Arduino not working adter `brltty` update"*)](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=269975) on ArchLinux BBS.

`brltty` has a rule for `idVendor=1a86, idProduct=7523`, which is the same as the CH340 serial converter on my Mega clone.

You can see your device id by using `lsusb` to get a list of your devices (unplug your Arduino, run `lsusb` then plug in your Arduino and run `lsusb` again to see which device appears).

In my case:

```
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 1a86:7523 QinHeng Electronics CH340 serial converter
```

Take a note of the ID and then open the brltty rules file:

```
sudo nano /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/90-brltty-device.rules
```

Search through the file until you find the entry for your ID:

```
# Device: 1A86:7523
# Baum [NLS eReader Zoomax (20 cells)]
ENV{PRODUCT}=="1a86/7523/*", ENV{BRLTTY_BRAILLE_DRIVER}="bm", GOTO="brltty_usb_run"
```

Now comment out the line:

```
# Device: 1A86:7523
# Baum [NLS eReader Zoomax (20 cells)]
# ENV{PRODUCT}=="1a86/7523/*", ENV{BRLTTY_BRAILLE_DRIVER}="bm", GOTO="brltty_usb_run"
```

Save and close the file then reboot.

After the reboot the `/dev/ttyUSB0` port was available again in the Arduino IDE.

Comment: This is great, especially for folks who do need this brltty service! As a side note, you can reload the udev rules without a reboot by running `sudo udevadm control --reload-rules`.

Comment: That's cleaner and worked perfectly, thanks.

Comment: I don't see how this is supposed to be "much less invasive", but ok. I think using `systemctl` commands to manage the service units is the way to go, especially since it exists to manage the very service units responsible for the conflicts.

Comment: A less invasive version is to copy the 90-brltty-device.rules file to `/etc/udev/rules.d/` instead, and do the edit there. That way it will not be overwritten in future updates.

Comment: This is together with reloading the udev rules as @user60561 explained in his comment is what works on Pop!_OS 22.04 (ubuntu 22.04).

Comment: Thank you!! To me this is much less invasive because it doesn't disable the entire service and instead addresses the actual root conflict: an overly-broad udev rule. The service itself is not at fault, so it shouldn't need to be removed, especially since that leaves anyone who _does_ need this assistive technology without a solution!

Answer (score 8):

This is just to highlight the excellent comment by @EvgEnZh and add a little something.   There is more than just one service that needs to be disabled on Manjaro.   For me it was the following:

List the services with:

```
 $ systemctl list-units | grep brltty
  brltty.path                             loaded active running   Default BRLTTY Instance
  brltty@-etc-brltty.conf.service         loaded active running   BRLTTY Instance: /etc/brltty.conf
  system-brltty.slice                     loaded active active    Slice /system/brltty
  system-brltty\x2ddevice.slice           loaded active active    Slice /system/brltty-device
```

And then disable them with:

```
$ sudo systemctl mask brltty.path
$ sudo systemctl stop brltty.path
$ sudo systemctl mask system-brltty\x2ddevice.slice
$ sudo systemctl stop system-brltty\x2ddevice.slice
$ sudo systemctl mask system-brltty.slice
$ sudo systemctl stop system-brltty.slice
$ sudo systemctl mask brltty@-etc-brltty.conf.service
$ sudo systemctl stop brltty@-etc-brltty.conf.service
```

I'm not sure if all of them need to be masked, but just masking and stopping brltty.path did not work for me.

Comment: Nice, I like this. No need for extra files to modify and then track around/worry about. Thanks for posting.

Comment: I used `systemctl list-units | grep brltty` to find that my system had `brltty-udev.service` running. Afterwards I used `systemctl mask brltty-udev.service` and then `systemctl stop brltty-udev.service` to stop the service. When I now connect my device, in my case a Wemos D1 mini, the `/dev/ttyUSB0` is not disconnected anymore and I can see the port in the Arduino IDE. So different device, same method :).

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 22.04, and needed to mask & stop the `brltty-udev.service` unit as well, as per above comment from @Adriaan

Answer (score 0):

Commenting out the offending lines in brltty worked for me too

I have quite a few usbuarts and it was very frustrating to find them all vanished but still working under previous Ubuntu and Windows!

from lsmod

```
Bus 001 Device 019: ID 10c4:ea60 Silicon Labs CP210x UART Bridge
Bus 001 Device 021: ID f055:9800 MicroPython Pyboard Virtual Comm Port in FS Mode
```

For safety I commented out both 10c4:ea60 and 10c4:ea80

But honestly I'm mad. Supporting our blind (or deaf, or wheelchair bound) friends is admirable.

How can they make a mistake like that. Taking down usbuarts from 3 different manufacturers. The CP210x is obviously a popular chip.

I was tempted to just delete 85-brltty.rules

Which is the exact opposite of what those who decided to add built in support for braille intended.